# Find all ship names beginning with the letter R

Tags: sql, sql-server

My tables:

- Classes(class, type, country, numGuns, bore, displacement)
- Ships(name, class, launched)
- Battles(name, date)
- Outcomes(ship, battle, result)

My query:

```
select name from ships where name like 'r%' union all select ship from outcomes where ship like 'r%'
```

It produced the correct result but shows error like:

```
Wrong
Your query produced correct result set on main database, but it failed test on second, checking database
* Wrong number of records (more by 4)
```

[image]

Comment: please provide some explanation concerning the structure of tur db... what r the foreign keys among ur tables if there are any? and hte relation btwn ur tables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNION ALL adds the records from the second select to the first set.

Since you are looking for a list of ships, you don't want to see the same ship returned twice if it appears in both sets.

Instead just use UNION which will remove the duplicates

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct query:

```
SELECT name
FROM ships
WHERE name LIKE 'R%'
UNION
SELECT ship
FROM outcomes
WHERE ship LIKE 'R%'
```